# Serialize an object directly to a JObject instead of to a string in json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

How might one serialize an object directly to a `JObject` instance in JSON.Net? What is typically done is to convert the object directly to a json *string* like so:

```
string jsonSTRINGResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObj);
```

One could then *deserialize* that back to a `JObject` as follows:

```
JObject jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonSTRINGResult);
```

That seems to work, but it would seem like this way has a double performance hit (serialize and then deserialize). Does `SerializeObject` internally use a `JObject` that can be accessed somehow? Or is there some way to just serialize directly to a `JObject`?

Comment: Why would you want to work with a JObject in your code over the native type/class?

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm

Comment: In short, it allows Json.Net to take care of all the hard serialization stuff, allowing me to do some things I want to do with the final serialization result, which will not be to json. If you want to know (though this is irrelevant to the specific problem), I want to serialize to XML in a way that attributes are used for properties instead of XML child elements, as the JSON.Net XML serializer (understandably) does, with maybe some other customizations.

Comment: Eser, please post that as the answer, just make sure to give a one liner code example (here it is: JObject.FromObject(obj)). That does it though!

Comment: Great question, I was looking for this one. This gets very handy when you are working with custom json serialization, or building a serialization framework which supports multiple serialization formats. +1

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use `FromObject` static method of `JObject`

```
JObject jObj = JObject.FromObject(someObj)
```

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_FromObject.htm

Comment: Beware, this is *NOT* equivalent to SerializeObject+DeserializeObject. The output of this function is slightly different, comparing the two with `JToken.DeepEquals` will most likely be `false`. This is due to partial loss of information during de/serialization which `FromObject` does not simulate. If you want to mimic an object you recieved say, from REST API, this probably wont work.

Answer (score 21):

Please note that the `JObject` route suggested in [Eser's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33088540/465053) will work *only* for non-array CLR objects. It results in below exception if you try converting an Array object to `JObject`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
> in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

So in case it is an array object, then you should use `JArray` instead as shown in the code snippet below:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JArray jArray = JArray.FromObject(someArrayObject);
```

Answer (score 12):

To combine everything: use JToken for everything (Objects AND Arrays).

```cs
JToken token = JToken.FromObject(someObjectOrArray);
```

Then check through `token.Type` which [`JTokenType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm) it is (Object, Array or otherwise).