# Parsing an Object to an JObject

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Good Evening,

i'll try to Parse an Object to an JObject.

[This](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAek0q) Fiddle demonstrates my Problem, and the code is below:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static JObject Parameters { set; get; }
    public static List<User> Users {get;set;}
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
        Parameters = new JObject();
        Users.Add(new User{UserId=1,Username="First User"});
        Users.Add(new User{UserId=2,Username="Second User"});
        
        Parameters.Add("Method", "AddUsers");
        Parameters.Add("Users", JArray.FromObject(Users));
        Console.WriteLine(Parameters);
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> {
>  "Method": "AddUsers",
>  "Users": "[{\"UserId\":1,\"Username\":\"First User\"},{\"UserId\":2,\"Username\":\"Second User\"}]"
> }
> ```

This is an simplified Object Structure of my real Problem. It escapes my Json what leads me to Point that the WebRequest is failing because of an invalid Request Body.

How do i have to Serialize my Object correctly?

Best Regards
Daniel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize an object directly to a JObject instead of to a string in json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33088297/serialize-an-object-directly-to-a-jobject-instead-of-to-a-string-in-json-net). See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9v02DB

Comment: I like this more than my actual Solution. I like the Notation `JArray.FromObject(Users)` more cause its shorter. Thanks canton7

Comment: It's also a lot cheaper: you're not serializing your object to a string, and then parsing it back out into objects

Answer (score 0):

I found the Answer after writing the Question.

I solved the Problem by adding the Parameter like this

```
Parameters.Add("Users", JProperty.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Users)));
```

Comment: I think you really want `Parameters["Users"] = Users;`

Comment: You could also just create an anonymous object and serialise that.

Comment: Thanks @Llama. for answering.  I'll prefer the way from canton7